# I would like to write a script that organizes my drum library

Tags: regex, bash, unix, find

So I would like to create a Bash script that organizes my Drum Library.  I would like to input the string 'kick' and have it recursively search a specified directory.  It should find all directories within the directory with the string 'kick' and copy its contents to a separate directory.  (Preferably emptying out the directory and not just copying the folder over).  I am running on Mac Terminal and I have included the code I have come up with so far but It is not doing exactly what I would like.  I think the problem lies in the line of code with 'find'

Also in the new directory I'm grouping the final files in new directories by 128.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i numFiles
declare -i numDirs
mkdir ./temp

ceildivide(){
local num
num=$1
echo $(( (num + 127) / 128 ))
}

find -E /Users/dot/Documents/_Sound\ Library/Drums\ \&\ Samples -regex ".*$1.*" -exec cp {} ./temp/ \;

numFiles=`ls ./temp | wc -l`
numDirs=$(ceildivide $numFiles)

for i in $(seq 1 $numDirs); do
   mkdir $1_$i;
    ls ./temp/ |head -n 128 > $1_$i/$1_$i.index
            for x in `cat $1_$i/$1_$i.index`; do mv ./temp/$x $1_$i; done

done

rm -rf ./temp
```

Comment: you need to define the function before you call it.

Comment: parentheses do different things in different flavours of regular expressions. Try `-regex ".*$1.*"`

Comment: Also, for efficiency, do `-exec cp {} ./temp +` -- that reduced the number of times cp gets invoked

Comment: Also, while debugging your script, add `set -v -x` to the top of it.

Comment: I took the parentheses out and got the same result.  I'm noticing that the find command isn't going through ALL the folders.  It's missing a whole bunch of folders labeled kick.  Their are a lot of folders labeled kickS with an S.  Is it factoring this as well?

Comment: I added an updated Script